# Suppose a password of length 5 is chosen at random from integers 1-5.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability of the event B that the integer 1 appears earlier in the password than the integer 3? No repetitions.

So I originally thought it was the probability of drawing an odd number at the 2nd to 5th placement , times the probability of drawing a 3 given 1.

I just need a bit of guidance to see if I'm heading in the right direction. This is my hardest subject and I'm not too good at it.

Comment: Are numbers allowed to be repeated?  If so, what does the sequence 13155 count as?  1 before 3? 1 after 3?

Comment: No they're not sorry about that, I just updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Would it be any different if it were the other way round - i.e., 3 were to appear before 1?

Think symmetry! The solution actually requires no calculation.

Comment: The probability that 3 would appear before 1 is the same as 1 before 3, so is it 3/5 since it's the probability of having any odd number first?

Comment: Yes you are right in that the probabilities are the same. Hence the probability of occurrence for either of those is 1/2. Your problem statement does not say anything about odd number occurring first. That should be inconsequential.

Comment: Ok I see now, the reason it is 1/2 is because they are equally likely of coming before the other, right?

Comment: Yup :) Bang on!

Answer (score 1):

If numbers aren't allowed to be repeated, the total number of sequences with no restriction is $5!$.  The restriction that 1 comes before 3 can be done in the following way: Pick what two spaces are occupied by the 1 and 3 (the order will be automatically determined), then for the remaining three locations choose what number occupies each.  $\binom{5}{2} \cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1$.

Thus, $Pr(1\text{ before }3) = \frac{(5\cdot 4)\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{2!\cdot 5!} = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

```
I can give you even easier solution which would clear your concepts. It would help you in problem solving.
Total outcomes- 5! 
1st case-
1_ _ _ _
 4 3 2 1 -> These numbers are how many numbers can come here. 
So no. of outcomes 4! (4*3*2*1)
2nd case-
_1_ _ _ 
So 3 cannot come in 1st place so outcomes satisfying the given 
conditions are 3*3*2*1=18
3rd case-
_ _ 1 _ _
So 3 cant come in first 2 places so outcomes are- 3*2*2*1=12
4th case-
_ _ _ 1 _
Outcomes-3*2*1*1=6
Fifth Case-
_ _ _ _ 1
Outcomes= 0
Adding all the sums- 4!+18+12+6=60
So P(1 before 3)- 60/120=1/2
```

Comment: "Easier" is a relative term.  In this case, yes, you were able to effectively brute force an approach, but it is to your and the reader's benefit to have an approach which can be applied to a much larger scenario, such as a string 100 digits long.  I don't know about you but I wouldn't want to spend the time writing out all 100 cases separately.

Comment: Read carefully- "It was meant to clear concepts"